# Issue on running posenet locally

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to run posenet locally without the need of an internet connection.
I copied the scripts in the following locations "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs", [https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/posenet"](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/posenet%22) and placed them in separate js files and linked them in the html document.

Everything works fine, but when I try to run the ResNet version I get the following error

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/savedmodel/posenet/resnet50/float/model-stride32.json. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.**

This is my html file

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
  <script src="tf.js"></script>
  <!-- Load Posenet -->
  <script src="posenet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img id='cat' src='index.jpg ' />
</body>
<!-- Place your code in the script tag below. You can also use an external .js file -->
<script>
  var flipHorizontal = false;

  var image = document.getElementById('cat');

  posenet.load({
    architecture: 'ResNet50',
    outputStride: 32
  }).then(function(net) {
    const pose = net.estimateSinglePose(image, {
      flipHorizontal: true
    });
    return pose;
  }).then(function(pose) {
    console.log(pose);
  })
</script>

</html>
```

Please provide a solution. Thanks in advance.